# Full-color isekai manhwa/manhua female lead dies by gunshot, goes into the body of someone being strangled, then picks a cat

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, webcomics

I found this full-colored isekai, fantasy manhwa/manhua on an aggregate website like Asurascans.com. I believe it starts with a black-haired woman being shot and falling off a roof. She then proceeds to wake up in the body of another woman who’s being strangled by the throat. She later finds out she’s been isekai’d into this game she was playing.

As she’s struggling to free herself, she notices these options next to her— and manages to pick a cat. She was struggling to choose while being strangled and all. I don’t think the cat is even really labeled as an option, but she manages to do it anyway. And somehow that cat kinda saves her? And she later finds out the cat can transform into a human?

And this cat-person she chose also is something like the game master, since he later takes her to this house where all these awesome items from the game are stored. And he gives her this earring that transforms into a gun when imbued with magic power. But I think she might have some issue with using magic if I remember right. And she has this contract with him that might allow her to use his within a certain range.

Oh and there’s this kind of revenge aspect to this I think? With the character she’s possessed? Which kinda meshes with, well, how she was killed/betrayed in the very first chapter, I think.

And this is only within the first few chapters. 5 at most, really, but I doubt it’s even 3. I do wish I could remember more identifying details like their hair colors, since finding this by plot.. albeit pretty unique, seems kinda impossible.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How long ago was this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *[The Princess Back From Hell](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-princess-back-from-hell)*, a manhua.

> After taking revenge on the ex-boyfriend who used to abuse her, **she died and transmigrated as the heroine of the popular otome game "Rose Spiral".** She found out that the targets who could be captured possessed evil intentions, approaching the female lead only to use her. The frozen heart of a reborn girl burns with hatred, and a revenge plan slowly unfolds. While attacking and taking revenge on the men, will she learn to love and be loved again?

The opening scene includes the main character, with brown hair, on the roof of a building with multiple people pointing guns at her. She jumps off instead of being shot, and transmigrates to the game she worked on as the main character.

[image: Standoff on the roof; jumping to her death]

Her brother comes to greet her, and promptly starts strangling her. She is rescued by pressing on the cat icon in the status window that opens, causing a cat to appear out of nowhere and attack him.

[image: Cat appears from dialog box and attacks brother]

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tag combination `Reincarnated in a Game World` and `revenge`, filtered to manhua.